# 2x2 subplot with legend on the side

Tags: tabularx, figure-placement

I have 4 plots in the form of images. I want to have their legend (another image) on the right. I have 2 issues:

1. The legend image is not vertically aligned to the 2x2 of plots to its (right/left). I tried using vspace but that seems to not work either
2. (less important) The legend is on the left and making it move to the right break the code

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXX}
        \multirow{2}{0.2\textwidth}{
        \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth, height=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
                
        &   \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\caption{b} 
        &   \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\caption{b2}\\
        
        &   \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}\caption{c}
        &   \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}\caption{c2}       
    
    \end{tabularx}   
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Use two tabulars 1) for the legend and another for the rest. Align them using `\begin{tabular}[b] ` etc.  Please also confirm you want the captions inline to the side of the image, left or right? A full MWE is always recommended, you will get better response. A hand-sketch of what you want to achieve will also make it clearer.